# БД реального времени firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Google предоставляет realtime DB, не могу понять что значит БД реального времени, типа данные могут синхронизироваться с данными у пользователей в режиме реального времени?

Answer (score 1):

Да, вы правы. Все изменения, которые будут проведены пользователями и все новые записи, которые пользователи добавят, будут сразу же отображены у всех пользователей.

Comment: Что такое БД реального времени? уместно ли использовать такое слово здесь, разве это не применяется только в промышленных масштабах где большая ориентация на метку времени,( что то я не понимаю)

Comment: А почему это здесь не уместно? У вас все автоматически обновляется независимо от вас. Это и есть БД реального времени в данном случае

Comment: Примерно понял, то есть не обязательно работать с синхронизацией по временным меткам, а можно ли эту бд использовать как обычную БД и хранить там данные за которыми пользователь обращается время от времени.

Comment: Можно, это надо настраивать только. Можно использовать как локальную бд

Comment: Последний вопрос, что значит 100 одновременных соединений в бесплатной версии, достаточно ли это будет для приложения с установкой более 100 тысяч к примеру.